# C# Entity Model won't correctly save changes to SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here's a brief summary of my code - it was written a long time ago and there are over 50 properties all written this way, yet when I added a new one, both in the model and within the ViewModel, it refuses to save changes:

From the view I have:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PhoneNumber )
```

From the ViewModel I have:

```
public string Registration {get;set;}
```

From the controller we have:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveVehicleInfo(VehicleViewModel VM){

    Vehicle vehicle = Mapper.Map<VehicleViewModel, Vehicle>(VM); (Automapper library)
    var changes = false;
    Vehicle dbVehicle = await context.Vehicles.FindAsync(vehicle.ID)

    //A load more properties etc

    string PhoneNumberChange = "";
    if (dbVehicle.PhoneNumber != vehicle.PhoneNumber)
    {
        PhoneNumberChange = " - Phone Number changed to " + vehicle.PhoneNumber + " from " + dbVehicle.PhoneNumber;
        dbVehicle.PhoneNumber = vehicle.PhoneNumber;
        changes = true;
    }

    //At the end:

    _db.Vehicles.Attach(dbVehicle);
    _db.Entry(dbVehicle).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _db.Notes.Add(note);

    try
    {
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        var str = "";
    }
    return #stuff#;
}
```

I know this is not the best way of doing it, as I said it was written a long time ago.

On inspecting the item dbVehicle in this line:

```
    _db.Entry(dbVehicle).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

It correctly shows the dbVehicle.PhoneNumber as being my new value. It also shows this:

```
        PhoneNumberChange = " - Phone Number changed to NEWVALUE from OLDVALUE"
```

The save statement goes through, however SQL logs do not show the PhoneNumber even being included in the UPDATE statement. ALL other values save correctly, except this new one I've just done. I can manually enter it in the database, the savechangesasync method fires without throwing anything, I just cannot figure out why it's doing this.

Have cleaned/rebuilt whole solution. No idea what's going on.

Entity Framework Version 6.

Comment: you shouldn't need the `_db.Vehicles.Attach(dbVehicle);`  can you take that out and see what happens?

Comment: Could you show us how the entities are configured?

Comment: I think perhaps this was something going wrong in Entity Framework somewhere. After a lot of messing around, deleting the model and re-adding it seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think perhaps this was something going wrong in Entity Framework somewhere. After a lot of messing around, deleting the model and re-adding it seemed to fix the problem.